# What's a Thead in FOSMessageBundle

Tags: multithreading, symfony, message-bundle

I don't understand what the thread class is in FOSMessageBundle (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle).

Could you explain what it represents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thread is like a conversation, it contains a list of messages between the same participants.

---

A close look at the model class will help you understand how it works:

> A [thread](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle/blob/master/Model/Thread.php) contains a collection of [Message](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle/blob/master/Model/Message.php)s as well as
>   important [Metadata](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle/blob/master/Model/ThreadMetadata.php) about the thread.

```
/**
 * Messages contained in this thread.
 *
 * @var Collection|MessageInterface[]
 */
protected $messages;
/**
 * Thread metadata.
 *
 * @var Collection|ThreadMetadata[]
 */
protected $metadata;

/**
 * Users participating in this conversation.
 *
 * @var Collection|ParticipantInterface[]
 */
protected $participants;
```

Comment: thanks a lot mick , i just wonder if i can use this bundle as a chat component

Comment: Hi @TagarikdiDjakouba, yes you can definitely do a chat system from the bundle - actually, it is very easy to do - all the logic is already done for you.

Answer (score -1):

a thread contains message of different participants, like a forum